# How to find figures with even areas

Tags: python

We have shape with n angles and its coordinates. I need to divide that figure into 2 figures with the same area. Division is performed in parallel to the axis y. The task is to find such x-coordinate, which would comply with the terms.
Test,E.g

```
4 (n angles)
0 0 
0 2
2 2
2 0
```

The output must be 1
I wrote

```
n = int(input())
coordinates = []
for i in range(n):
    x,y = map(int,input().split())
    coordinates.append([x,y])

s = 0
for i in range(len(coordinates)-1):
    s += coordinates[i][0]*coordinates[i+1][1]
    s -= coordinates[i][1]*coordinates[i+1][0]
s = s/2
x = 0

print(s)
```

And after that I don't have any ideas what to do next..

Comment: If you want to brute force it, write a function that finds the areas of the two sub-shapes for a given x value, then do a binary search with it

Comment: Probably I am stupid, but isn't this just the arithmetic mean of the 4 x-coordinates, at least for convex figures?

Comment: @schwobaseggl. Pretty sure that's not the case, unless I'm missing the point myself

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, you are right. Just for some trivial cases... it's more complicated in general.

Comment: what do u mean by " n angles"?

Comment: @schwobaseggl. But there's still an analytic solution, at least for convex shapes, since you can use triangles to express area as a function of the split point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if the figure is always a rectangle (positioned vertically straight) then getting the mean is all it needs